# Angular Promise - $q.all not returning result and calling Post method several times not working

Tags: angularjs, promise, http-post, angular-promise, q

Am trying to call a `Post` method and then depending on the result I am going to call same `Post` method multiple times and return the result, using $q.all.

My `Post` method is :

```
getData: function (params, callback) {
                $http.post('service/myService', params)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        callback(null, data);
                    }).error(function (error) {
                        callback(error);
                    });
            }
```

I am calling it in below function, this function is recursive so if it contains `nextUrl` I am doing same thing until there is no object for `paging`:

```
var result = [];
var promises = [];
var checkForPaging = function (nextUrl, service, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var criteria = {
        url: url
    }
    var promise = service.getData(criteria, function (error, data) {
        if (data.statusCode == 200) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.body.items.length; i++) {
                result.push(data.body.items[i]);
            }
            if (data.body.paging != null && data.body.paging.next != null) {
                checkForPaging(data.body.paging.next.url, service, $q);
            } else{
               deferred.resolve(result);
            }
        }
    });

    promises.push(promise);
    $q.all(promises)
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then am calling this function from below and want to get the `result` back once all calls are complete:

```
checkForPaging(data.body.paging.next.url, myService, $q).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

The issue I am having is that it never hits the callback function above : `console.log(data)`. But I can see it calling the `Post` method several times.

If I resolve it like below then I can see after first `Post` it is hitting the callback above:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
           deferred.resolve(result);
       }, function (errors) {
           deferred.reject(errors);            
       });
```

Am I doing it right? How can I get the result back and call the Post method several times?

Let me know if it is not clear or have any questions!

Comment: Add return to getData $http

Comment: @Kindzoku what do you mean?

Comment: btw, why do you need $q.all?

Comment: so that it resolves all promises before hitting the callback function...

Comment: But there is no need to use all. Actually, you call `checkForPaging` next time only when your previous call is done (it's in callback).

Comment: I am new to angular & promises...so went for $q.all :) can you please update your answer with how I should chain the whole thing. I tried dfsq's answer but it calls it only once and it doesn't go inside the return service.getData(criteria, data) function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121237/discussion-between-kindzoku-and-zaki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/HqkFNo?p=preview I rewrited logic a bit.
You can catch the main idea.**

**UPDATE added promiseless solution**

1) Your service should return only promise:

```
this.getData = function(url, params){
    return $http.post(url, params); //You're just returning promise
}
```

2) You don't need $q.all, you can use single promise:

```
var result = [];

var deferred;

var checkForPaging = function (url) {

    if(!deferred){
        deferred = $q.defer();
    }

    //resolvind service promise
    newService.getData(url).then(
        //if ok - 200
        function(response){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.body.items.length; i++) {
                result.push(data.body.items[i]);
            }

            if (data.body.paging != null && data.body.paging.next != null){
            {
                return checkForPaging(data.body.paging.next.url);
            } else{
               deferred.resolve(result);
            }
        },
        //handle errors here
        function(error) {

        }
    );

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

3) You should call it like this:

```
checkForPaging('url').then(function(data){
    //here will be resolved promise
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with proper promise chaining:

```
var result = [];

var checkForPaging = function(nextUrl, service) {
    var criteria = {
        url: url
    }
    return service.getData(criteria, function(error, data) {
        if (data.statusCode == 200) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.body.items.length; i++) {
                result.push(data.body.items[i]);
            }
            if (data.body.paging != null && data.body.paging.next != null) {
                return checkForPaging(data.body.paging.next.url, service);
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
    });
}

checkForPaging(data.body.paging.next.url, myService).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

And getData:

```
getData: function(params) {
    return $http.post('service/myService', params)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tested it and now only hits the function once and doesn't go inside this function : return service.getData(criteria, function(error, data) {

Comment: getData also changes, there should not be any callback, instead it should return promise.